# Is it safe to remove oneconf?

Tags: services, oneconf

I use Xubuntu, but at this time I only have 1 GB RAM and the system is very slow. I started to remove services and tasks that I don't need.

I found that ***'oneconf'*** uses 14 MB RAM, which is too much for me. **Can I remove safely?** I found [that Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneConf), but I can't answer the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Software center depends on that service. You will figure it out if you try to remove it. BTW you can disable it using this approach by [David Anderson](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oneconf/+bug/894314)

```
sudo chmod a-x /usr/share/oneconf/oneconf-service
sudo chmod a-x /usr/share/oneconf/oneconf-query
sudo chmod a-x /usr/share/oneconf/oneconf-update
```

In other words: change permissions for these files.